# Is there a way to get big text in curses?

Tags: python, text, terminal, ncurses, curses

With big text I mean like an increased font-size or something like that. I know that usually the text can only be in one row but is there any way I can make it bigger like for a title?

Comment: curses only sends ANSI codes to the terminal, with limited control over position, color, and a minimum of other services. If you want fancy text formatting use a GUI library.

Comment: no (probably a duplicate).  curses doesn't do that, because curses deals with features which many terminals provide (VT100 double-size text isn't that popular)

Comment: No, but you could fake it by writing some icode that used it to turn each character of a string into an grid of say, `X` and `O` characters.

Comment: @martineau is there some kind of translator in the internet or do I have to write it myself?

Comment: I don't know of one off-hand, but think one might exist. Goggle "curses library big text" and/or "curses banner". Writing it yourself probably won't betoo hard, although you'd need some kind of "font" that contained the data needed for each character (which might be a bit tedious, but possible, to create).

Comment: [asciimatics](https://pypi.org/project/asciimatics/) looks promising.

Comment: It really does but its a hassle to implement.. I have found another simple library called [link](https://pypi.org/project/art/) art

Answer (score 1):

You could use an external program such as figlet http://www.figlet.org/ to generate large characters out of ASCII text:

```
 _ _ _          _   _     _     
| (_) | _____  | |_| |__ (_)___ 
| | | |/ / _ \ | __| '_ \| / __|
| | |   <  __/ | |_| | | | \__ \
|_|_|_|\_\___|  \__|_| |_|_|___/
```

which you can then split into separate lines and display using curses addstr.

Depending on your programming language, you could exec() or run figlet as an external command to generate variable text. Python has a [pyfiglet](https://pypi.org/project/pyfiglet/0.7/) module.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have already written the program using the art library now but maybe I'll try this one out too sometime