# Is there any way to draw large characters using ncursesw?

Tags: ncurses

I want to create a main page for a program I'm trying to write and basically, I want to print the title at the center with a large font and menu and the rest after that. What I'm looking for is any character set in ncursesw or just anything which will help me draw large characters for title more precisely

For this (in ncurses), I tried A_REVERSE attribute and printed the respective places white, something like this

Large text

[image: 1]

But other letters like z, g and t are hard to draw and they don't look good either.

Comment: If the title is static you can use an ASCII generator and just copy the result in your ncurses output, for example https://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=testall&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20 where the ANSI Regular or ANSI Shadow options seem to come close to what you want. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526895/is-there-a-way-to-get-big-text-in-curses.

Comment: I've tried it but ultimately chose to use regular text because it is bigger than I expected, Thanks for the ASCII generator